# How to understand OSM data structure of way

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

I want to extract some data from OSM, and then save these as json format, But I don't now the structure of the `key:way`, How do I convert it as latlng?

Ex:
The way data is `0101000020110F0000FC0D5DF0B2886941E95302C3BA554441`
I want to convert it to (`latitude`, `longitude`)

[The `way` data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0EEK.png)

Comment: Your way is int the WKB (Well Known Binary). What GIS are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question and explain where you obtained this data from, *exactly*. OSM typically uses XML whereas the thing from your question is not XML.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry，My English is bad( I'm a Japanese).So, Someone may confused about my question.
I have converted OSM data to postgis, and I have found the value from `way` not a latlng.

I solved it, The nature of the problem is [how-do-i-convert-the-coordinate-data-from-osm-into-actual-longitude-latitude-poi](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163173/how-do-i-convert-the-coordinate-data-from-osm-into-actual-longitude-latitude-poi).

In postgre, only use `select ST_AsText(ST_Transform(value, 4326))`

Thanks all ^-^